# Borrar elementos repetidos de una tabla

Tags: base-de-datos, sqlite

El metodo coge unos elementos de una tabla y los coloca en otra tabla, lo que quiero es que si se vuelven a añadir los mismos elementos estos se eliminen o bien que no se puedan añadir si ya existen.

```
public void añadirErrores(int[] pregMalas) {
    int preg;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteDatabase dbw = getWritableDatabase();
    for (int i = 0; i < pregMalas.length; i++) {
        preg = pregMalas[i];
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM preguntas where id = " + preg, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("idpreg", c.getString(0));
                values.put("pregunta", c.getString(2));
                values.put("respuesta_correcta", c.getString(3));
                values.put("respuesta_falsa_1", c.getString(4));
                values.put("respuesta_falsa_2", c.getString(5));
                values.put("recurso", c.getString(6));
                dbw.insert("testErrores", null, values);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
    }
    dbw.close();
    db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola tienes 2 formas de hacerlo

1: Es con Java realizando un Select y esos datos almacenarlos en una lista luego recorrer la lista y eliminar los duplicados con java 8 Seria asi :

```
    ArrayList<TuObjeto> listaSql = new ArrayList<>();
    //aqui debes llenar tu lista
    //luego crear un stream en base a tu lista
    Stream<TuObjeto> stream = listaSql.stream().distinct();
    //luego puedes recorrer tu stream y obtener los datos
```

2 SQLite:

```
    BEGIN;

    CREATE TABLE test1(first INTEGER, second TEXT, third TEXT)
    --WITHOUT ROWID --SQLite 3.8.2
    ;

    INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (0, 'zero' , 'OK' );
    INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (0, 'zero' , 'OK' );
    INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (0, 'zero' , 'OK' );
    INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (1, 'one'  , 'OK' );
    INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (2, 'two'  , 'OK' );
    INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (3, 'three', 'OK' );

    --Para ver las columnas ocultas.
    SELECT *
    , oid --SQLite
    FROM test1
    ;

    --Para ver sólo los registros duplicados.
    SELECT COUNT(*), first, second, third FROM test1 GROUP BY first, second,third HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1);

    --SQLite.
    --Para borrar todos los repetidos menos uno usando OID.
    DELETE FROM test1
    WHERE oid NOT IN (SELECT min(oid) FROM test1 GROUP BY first, second, third)
    ;

    --Para ver lo que queda finalmente en la tabla.
    SELECT * FROM test1;

    DROP TABLE test1;

    ROLLBACK;
```

Espero te sirva Saludos.